# Difference between MOV and CPY instruction in ARM ISA

Tags: arm, embedded

What is the difference between MOV and CPY instruction in ARM ISA?

I cannot seem to find valid difference.

Comment: Same instruction, different mnemonic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Which ARM core?

According to for ARMv7: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/cb/Application-Level-Architecture/Instruction-Details/Alphabetical-list-of-instructions/CPY
They are synonyms, meaning they translate to the same instruction.